# Expressjs Invalid JSON when data is just a string

Tags: json, express

Searching for this has proven difficult, since most people asking have an object they have serialized (incorrectly).

I am just sending a `string`. Not an object, just a `string`. Here is the request right before it's fired off. `JSON.parse` can handle the payload just fine. The string is properly double quoted, as per [the spec](http://www.json.org/).

[image]

Express JS just gives the very simple error: `Error: invalid json`. What do I need to do to send just a string as a payload?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the `express.bodyParser()`, which is based on the `connect` `json` middleware operates in [strict mode](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/ced45a436e65039bacf215e2c8ec4ad5cfe3d06a/lib/middleware/json.js#L74). Strict mode will only parse objects or arrays, sticking strictly to the JSON spec.

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>   realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>   list, or associative array.
>
> An ordered list of values. In most
>   languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.

If you want the non-strict version, you can optionally get that using an option which will just use `JSON.parse`, which is OK parsing a string representation of a raw JSON value like 'true', '"stackoverflow"', '42', and so on.

```
app.use(connect.bodyParser({strict: false}));
```

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, but I am curious why `JSON.parse` doesn't fail if this is the case.

Comment: I think that's just an implementation convenience, especially since this is javascript and parsing JSON in javascript is more or less equivalent to `eval`. In any other language, the JSON parsing function would likely throw an exception for anything other than an object or array.

Comment: Actually, try `console.log(JSON.parse("\"Test\""));` in Node. It works.

Comment: Answer updated with a link to connect. It is parsing in strict mode by default.

Comment: Is there a performance penalty to operating without string mode?

Comment: Uh, check the link to the code in my answer. "strict mode" adds 2 `!=` operations. So there's no meaningful performance difference between strict and loose modes.

Comment: For me, this call needed to be BEFORE this call `app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'}));`