# Express - Why does my array with a trailing comma timeout?

Tags: node.js, express

In Express, I have a `router.post` endpoint that should accept an object with a specific structure. The object it accepts looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "tableName": "patients",
        "tableColumns": [
            "id",
            "fName",
            "lName",
            "email"
        ]
    },
    {
        "tableName": "providers",
        "tableColumns": [
            "id",
            "fName",
            "lName"
        ]
    }
]
```

I don't intend to provide it with any data structures different from this, but I may be receiving data from sources that I can't control. This object is parsed without any errors, but when I put a comma at the end of one of the arrays...

```
[
    {
        "tableName": "patients",
        "tableColumns": [
            "id",
            "fName",
            "lName",
            "email", //<<<<<<<<<
        ]
    },
    {
        "tableName": "providers",
        "tableColumns": [
            "id",
            "fName",
            "lName"
        ]
    }
]
```

...the request times out. It just stops going. No errors are thrown, it just doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What are you using to parse the request body?

Comment: To parse req.body I use bodyParser.

Comment: If I upload invalid JSON to `body-parser`, it throws an error. Can you show how you're using it?

Comment: To @robertklep point, a trailing comma is considered invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that you shouldn't be using invalid JSON in body-parser (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18108807/5623385)), at least not with the default settings. body-parser uses [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) to parse JSON. By default, connect runs in [strict mode](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/ced45a436e65039bacf215e2c8ec4ad5cfe3d06a/lib/middleware/json.js#L74), only allowing properly formatted JSON to be parsed.